# LayerSlider Responsive Slider for ExpressionEngine

Tags: extension

Does exists something similar to [LayerSlider Responsive WordPress Slider Plugi](http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin-/1362246) for EE?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the [non-Wordpress version of that plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-jquery-slider-plugin/922100)? You would just take the static HTML markup that the plugin uses to build and apply animations and replace them with markup coming from a loop in EE.  Similar to that, I've used [Royal Slider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/) with EE, as well as [ResponsiveSlides.js](http://responsiveslides.com) - essentially anything that uses HTML, CSS and jQuery for a slider effect can be used with EE - you just have to build your content model to suit whichever you choose.

Comment: Yeah - I saw a standalone version of it. Maybe it will be worth to create EE extension based on it :)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an image slider plugin for EE, but you can easily roll your own using something like Cycle - http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/ with your images either directly within EE's native content management, using something like Grid or Matrix, or in conjunction with one of the larger photo add-ons for EE like Channel Images or Photo Frame.

Comment: Well, I'm looking for something which can handle layers and an editor for those "slides" like that mentioned in the OP

Comment: As the others have said, you really don't need a plugin or extension to setup a slider. Simply use EE's native content channels and channel fields to setup the necessary structures, and output as you need in the template for your chosen JS plugin. This is the beauty of EE!

Comment: Depending on the number of slides - I've done this with a single "slideshow" type channel with fields for image upload, Slide heading, slide tagline, linked url and so forth. It has enabled clients to create their own slider content, and works pretty well.